# How to get hypervolume calculation for Pareto Front in python?

Tags: python, multi-objective-optimization

I hope that this Stack Exchange channel is the right place for this.

I'm trying to analyze a multiobjective optimization problem. I'm wanting to use the [hypervolume calculation](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Hypervolume-indicator-in-two-dimensions-for-a-set-A-a-1-a-4-R-2_fig1_235709701) to benchmark the quality of my results. I'm working in Python, and can't seem to figure out a package that I can install that will do this. I'm wanting to find a package with a function `hypervolume` that does the following:

`hv = hypervolume(pointset, reference_point)`

I've looked briefly online and tried to install [PyGMO](https://esa.github.io/pygmo2/install.html) but I can't get this to install. It keeps raising the error: 'the following packages are causing the inconsistency'. I've also tried using the [DEAP](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/deap/benchmarks/tools.html?highlight=hypervolume#) package, but can't get it to work properly. Has anyone had experience calculating hypervolume in Python before? Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Hi @BSplitter welcome to or.stackexchange. A quick Google search lead to https://pymoo.org/misc/indicators.html . Maybe that suffices?

Comment: @Sune I saw this link as well, but it mentions that the Hypervolume indicator comes from DEAP. I ended up going straight to DEAP's version because of that comment. But I just tried it out and I believe it works. Thank you.

Comment: Very good. I will just add it as an answer then, so the question can be marked with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Pymoo package has the machinery to compute the hypervolume. From the documentation, in the "Performance indicator" section, they describe several performance indicators (generational distance, generational distance plus, inverted generational distance, inverted generational distance plus, and  the hypervolume).

They provide the following example

```
from pymoo.indicators.hv import HV
from pymoo.problems import get_problem
import numpy as np

# The pareto front of a scaled zdt1 problem
pf = get_problem("zdt1").pareto_front()

# The result found by an algorithm
A = pf[::10] * 1.1

ref_point = np.array([1.2, 1.2])

ind = HV(ref_point=ref_point)
print("HV", ind(A))
```